# Error is shown while connecting to MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

I tried to connect to MongoDB and got this error

My code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


uri = "mongodb+srv://root:87954389@cluster0.wuyjxer.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"


client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client["Users"]
collection = db["users"]
post = {"_id": 0, "name":"User1"}
collection.insert_one(post)
```

Error:

```
ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-02.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-01.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-00.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 649d994cc30ecaea12f34585, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-00.wuyjxer.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-00.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-01.wuyjxer.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-01.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-02.wuyjxer.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ac-ibwngp9-shard-00-02.wuyjxer.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>]>
```

Comment: This might help https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors